# Making a JComboBox change to different panel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, switch-statement, jcombobox

With Swing the code just auto prints the default within the switch statement.

```
selectAddPage.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        String selectProductType[] = {"Supplier", "Customer", "Employee"};
        JComboBox jcomboBox = new JComboBox(selectProductType);
        String selection = String.valueOf(jcomboBox.getSelectedIndex());

        //mainWindow.remove(pAddSupplier);
        
        switch (selection) {
            case "Supplier":
                AddSupplier sup = new AddSupplier();
                mainWindow.setContentPane(sup.pAddSupplier);
                mainWindow.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Add Customer");
                break;
            case "Customer":
                AddCustomer cust = new AddCustomer();
                mainWindow.setContentPane(cust.pAddCustomer);
                mainWindow.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Add Customer");
                break;
            case "Employee":
                AddEmployee emp = new AddEmployee();
                mainWindow.setContentPane(emp.pAddEmployee);
                mainWindow.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Add Employee");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Add Supplier");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) - it is made for exactly this purpose. If you get stuck, [edit] to post a [mre] of your attempt.

Comment: 1) `JComboBox jcomboBox = new JComboBox(selectProductType);` Don't create a combo box here. Since this is created within the listener, it's not the combo which created the event, and the following code will always return the initial item (`Supplier`). 2) `String.valueOf(jcomboBox.getSelectedIndex());` can be replaced by `jcomboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();` 3) The first `System.out.println("Add Customer");` is in the `case` for the supplier. 4) This code is quite random and has more wrong with it, than is correct.